# Cannot make support bottomsheet not-hideable when in Expanded state

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to make a bottomsheet using google support library. The goal is to have a sheet that:

- Can be hidden programmatically only
- Its height is calculated automatically
- Is defined statically in xml

So far so good, simple stuff. There is also this promising `isHideable()` which defaults to false.

But the bottomsheet seems to ignore the `isHideable` when the sheet is set to `STATE_EXPANDED` (although its not going to cover the whole screen). The only way to make it unhideable is to set a peek height (which I don't want). Is there a way to have it expanded and not-hideable without setting the height manually (or via layout change triggers)

Here is the (super slim) code used:

**Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setHideable(false);
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text=":) :) :)"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Behavior**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest but hackish way I've found so far:

```
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            behavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheet.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

And of course when there is need to hide it firstly call `setHideable(true)`.

This is just a workaround that might lead to weird behavior.